# calculus 1 prove for |a-b|

Tags: inequality

if this happens:
b≠0
$$ |a-b|≤b^2 $$
so need to prove this:
$$\frac{|a|}{|b|} ≤ |b|+1 $$
this what I Tried
$$\frac{|a|}{|b|} ≤ |b|+1 = |a|≤b^2+|b| $$

$$ |a|-|b|≤b^2 $$
$$ |a-b|≥ |a|-|b|  $$
thanks guys

Comment: A general bit of proof advice: it's best to start from what you're given and move toward what you want to prove, rather than to start from what you want to prove and try to get back to what you're given, in which case you have to check the reasoning is bidirectional. If the desired result doesn't imply the assumption, the backwards strategy can never work.

Comment: @anton5450  It's wrong for $a=b=0.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $b \ne 0$ and $|a-b|≤b^2$.

From $|a|-|b| \le |a-b|$ we get

$$|a|-|b| \le b^2=|b|^2.$$

This gives

$$\frac{|a|}{|b|}-1 \le |b|.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $b-b^2\le a\le b+b^2$,$$|a|\le\max_\pm|b\pm b^2|,$$i.e. $\tfrac{|a|}{|b|}\le\max_\pm|1\pm b|$. By the triangle inequality, $|b|+1$ is an upper bound on $|1\pm b|$ for each choice of the $\pm$ sign.